# Alterei o html do formulário, agora o arquivo php não responde

Tags: css, formulário, phpmailer, formulário-submeter

Boa tarde galera,
Estou na finalização de um projeto, e o arquivo php dos formulários não respondem. Tenho 02 formulários distintos na página, um deles tem input de envio de arquivo.
Nenhum deles está respondendo. Alguém consegue me dar uma luz???

```html
    <!-- Form -->
    <div class="clearfix">
     <form class="form contact-form" id="contact_form">
      <form action="contact_me.php" method="post">
         <div class="form-group">
           NOME: <input type="text" name="name" size="76" maxlength="100"required><br><br> 
                E-MAIL: <input type="text" name="email" size="30" maxlength="100" value="@"required>
                CIDADE: &#160;<input type="text" name="city" size="27" maxlength="70"><br><br> 
                SEXO:&#160;&#160;&#160;<input type="radio" name="genderm" value="Masculino"> Masculino | <input type="radio" name="genderf" value="Feminino"> Feminino <br><br> 

                                <div class="mb-20 mb-md-10">
                                    <h4>DEPARTAMENTO</h4>
                                    <select class="input-md form-control" name"selection">
                                        <option>ADMINISTRATIVO</option>
                                        <option>RECURSOS HUMANOS</option>
                                        <option>FINANCEIRO</option>
                                        <option>COMERCIAL</option>
                                        <option>DATA CENTER E ESTRUTURA</option>
                                        <option>INOVAÇÃO</option>
                                        <option>ESTATÍSTICA E MACHINE LEARNING</option>
                                        <option>SUPORTE E ATENDIMENTO AO CLIENTE</option>
                                        <option>GERENCIAMENTO E IMPLANTAÇÃO DE PROJETOS</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                         </div>


                            <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-2">
                                <div class="clearfix">

                                <div class="mb-20 mb-md-10">
                                    <h4>ANEXE SEU CURRICULO</h4>
                                    <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" name"send">

                                </div>                   

                                 <!-- Send Button -->
                                       <div class="align-left pt-10">
                                        <button class="submit_btn btn btn-mod btn-medium btn-round" id="submit_btn">Enviar Mensagem</button>
                                        </div>

                                <div id="result"></div>
                            </form>
                          </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </div>

                </div></div></div>


                    <!-- End Contact Form -->

                </div>
            </section>
            <!-- End Contact Section -->
```

> ```
>     PHP:
> ```

```
    <?php
if ($_POST) {
    $to_Email = "c2midia@gmail.com"; //Replace with recipient email address
    $subject  = 'Mensagem do site ' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; //Subject line for emails


    //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {

        //exit script outputting json data
        $output = json_encode(array(
            'type' => 'error',
            'text' => 'Request must come from Ajax'
        ));

        die($output);
    }

    //check $_POST vars are set, exit if any missing
    if (!isset($_POST["userName"]) || !isset($_POST["userEmail"]) || !isset($_POST["userCity"]) || !isset($_POST["userGenderf"]) || !isset($_POST["userGenderm"]) || !isset($_POST["userSend"])) {
        $output = json_encode(array(
            'type' => 'error',
            'text' => 'Campos Vazios!'
        ));
        die($output);
    }

    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
    $user_Name    = filter_var($_POST["userName"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Email   = filter_var($_POST["userEmail"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $user_City    = filter_var($_POST["userCity"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Genderf = filter_var($_POST["userGenderf"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Genderm = filter_var($_POST["userGenderm"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Send    = filter_var($_POST["userSend"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);



    //additional php validation
    if (strlen($user_Name) < 4) // If length is less than 4 it will throw an HTTP error.
        {
        $output = json_encode(array(
            'type' => 'error',
            'text' => 'Name is too short or empty!'
        ));
        die($output);
    }
    if (!filter_var($user_Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) //email validation
        {
        $output = json_encode(array(
            'type' => 'error',
            'text' => 'Please enter a valid email!'
        ));
        die($output);
    }


    //proceed with PHP email.
    $headers = 'From: ' . $user_Email . '' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $user_Email . '' . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    $sentMail = @mail($to_Email, $user_City, $user_Genderf, $user_Genderm, $user_Send, $user_Selection . "\r\n\n" . '-- ' . $user_Name . "\r\n" . '-- ' . $user_Email, $headers);

    if (!$sentMail) {
        $output = json_encode(array(
            'type' => 'error',
            'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'
        ));
        die($output);
    } else {
        $output = json_encode(array(
            'type' => 'message',
            'text' => 'Olá ' . $user_Name . '! Recebemos seu email'
        ));
        die($output);
    }
}
?>
```

> CONTACT-FORM

```
/* ---------------------------------------------
 Contact form
 --------------------------------------------- */
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit_btn").click(function(){

    //get input field values
    var user_name = $('input[name=name]').val();
    var user_email = $('input[name=email]').val();   
    var user_city = $('input[name=city]').val();
    var user_gender = $('input[name=gender]').val();
    var user_send = $('input[name=send]').val();


    //simple validation at client's end
    //we simply change border color to red if empty field using .css()
    var proceed = true;
    if (user_name == "") {
        $('input[name=name]').css('border-color', '#e41919');
        proceed = false;
    }
    if (user_email == "") {
        $('input[name=email]').css('border-color', '#e41919');
        proceed = false;
    }

    //everything looks good! proceed...
    if (proceed) {
        //data to be sent to server
        post_data = {
            'userName': user_name,
            'userEmail': user_email,
            'userCity': user_city,
            'userGender': user_gender,
            'userSend' : user_send,

        };

        //Ajax post data to server
        $.post('contact_me.php', post_data, function(response){

            //load json data from server and output message     
            if (response.type == 'error') {
                output = '<div class="error">' + response.text + '</div>';
            }
            else {

                output = '<div class="success">' + response.text + '</div>';

                //reset values in all input fields
                $('#contact_form input').val('');
              }

            $("#result").hide().html(output).slideDown();
        }, 'json');

    }

    return false;
});

//reset previously set border colors and hide all message on .keyup()
$("#contact_form input").keyup(function(){
    $("#contact_form input").css('border-color', '');
    $("#result").slideUp();
});

});
```

Comment: Antes funcionava? O que vc mudou para ele deixar de funcionar? Aparece algum erro na página ou no console?

Comment: Sim, está aparecendo Input fields are empty!

Comment: Será que consegue me ajudar mais uma vez @hugocsl?

Comment: Cris nessa não consigo pq não sei nada de PHP, mas provavelmente foi algum input que vc removeu do form html e que ainda está no código do PHP, ai ele fica vazio pq não está preenchido. Ou então o action não está buscando os dados dos dois forms ao mesmo tempo na hora de enviar... eu não entendo muito dessa parte :/. Só te questionei, pois com mais detalhes fica mais fácil pra alguém te ajudar entende...

Comment: Ah sim, entendo perfeitamente. Você conhece alguma forma mais fácil de enviar estes formulários aos emails que não seja via php?

Comment: Desconheço infelizmente... quando eu preciso pego algo pronto... Mas procure por PHPMailer, tem uns tutoriais que podem te ajudar!

Comment: Legal, muito obrigada mais uma vez!!! :) Vou procurar sim.

Comment: se não tou em erro tu tens 2 tags de <form> e so 1 é que esta fechada. O erro pode vir dai. Depois se tens 2 formularios nao deviam estar separados ?? porque que esta um dentro do outro??

Comment: @joaodias mesmo assim o erro persiste...já corrigi a tag que estava aberta e continua informando que algum campo input está vazio.

Comment: podes postar o código para eu ver. Ou actualiza o teu código em cima para podermos ver

Comment: @joaodias acabei de editar, e estou recebendo um erro : PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estive aqui a corrigir o teu código espero que te ajude, basta só um formulário não vejo o porque de teres um form dentro de outro sem contar que tens tags a mais e algumas mal fechadas deixo-te aqui o código

```css
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 //This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
 echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
}
$namefirst = $_POST['name_first'];
$contacto = $_POST['contacto'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['comentario'];
$info = $_POST['check1'];
if(count($info) > 0){
   foreach($info as $item){
       $produtos .= $item ."\r\n";
   }
}
$email_from = 'info@ewewe.pt';//<== update the email address
$email_subject = "Nova Resposta ao Formulario";
$email_body = "Tem um novo pedido de informacoes da pessoa $namefirst . \r\n Contacto nº $contacto . \r\n Email: $visitor_email . \r\n " .
    "Aqui estão os produtos: \r\n $produtos . \r\n " .
    "Aqui estão os comentarios adicionais: \r\n $message . \r\n " .
$to = "info@mediascreen.pt";//<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: thank-you.html');
```

```html
<div class="clearfix">
  <form action="contact_me.php" method="post" class="form contact-form" id="contact_form">
    <div class="form-group">
      NOME: <input type="text" name="name" size="76" maxlength="100" required><br><br> E-MAIL: <input type="text" name="email" size="30" maxlength="100" value="@" required> CIDADE: &#160;<input type="text" name="city" size="27" maxlength="70"><br><br>      SEXO:&#160;&#160;&#160;
      <input type="radio" name="genderm" value="Masculino"> Masculino | <input type="radio" name="genderf" value="Feminino"> Feminino <br><br>

      <div class="mb-20 mb-md-10">
        <h4>DEPARTAMENTO</h4>
        <select class="input-md form-control" name "selection">
          <option>ADMINISTRATIVO</option>
          <option>RECURSOS HUMANOS</option>
          <option>FINANCEIRO</option>
          <option>COMERCIAL</option>
          <option>DATA CENTER E ESTRUTURA</option>
          <option>INOVAÇÃO</option>
          <option>ESTATÍSTICA E MACHINE LEARNING</option>
          <option>SUPORTE E ATENDIMENTO AO CLIENTE</option>
          <option>GERENCIAMENTO E IMPLANTAÇÃO DE PROJETOS</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-2">
      <div class="clearfix">

        <div class="mb-20 mb-md-10">
          <h4>ANEXE SEU CURRICULO</h4>
          <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" name "send">

        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Send Button -->
      <div class="align-left pt-10">
        <button class="submit_btn btn btn-mod btn-medium btn-round" id="submit_btn">Enviar Mensagem</button>
      </div>

      <div id="result">

      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Cara, muito obrigada mesmo, mas ainda sim o arquivo php não responde. Ainda aparece que os campos estão vazios. :(

Comment: o teu codigo php nao pode estar junto ao formulario tem que estar no contact_me.php vou te deixar aqui um exemplo

Comment: Sim, ele está em um arquivo separado.

Comment: ai em cima tens um exemplo para um php meu que tinha tambem escolha multipla

Comment: estava aqui a ver o teu codigo esta certo pelo menos o php o erro deve estar no contact form mas tambem nao sou expert em php a ver se alguem deteta alguma coisa que eu nao veja

Comment: Cara, não consigo encontrar esse erro...consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ']' in contact_us.php on line 22